# floor gives unexpected result, and therefore so does focalWeight function from R's raster package

Tags: r, r-raster

I've used the `focalWeight` function in R's `raster` package to create focal "moving window" weight matrices for tens of thousands of images.  On a few dozen of the images the function does not behave as expected.  I expect a 3x3 matrix, but am returned a 1x3 matrix.

Upon digging into the problem I think it is due to the `floor` function which is called internally.

I'll demonstrate the problem below (I have a raster named `r`).  I'm running code from [.circular.weight](https://github.com/cran/raster/blob/master/R/focalWeight.R)

```
res(r)                               # raster resolution is 1
#[1] 1 1
rs <- res(r)
d <- 1                               # window diameter is 1
nx <- 1 + 2 * floor(d/rs[1])         # number of columns is 3
nx                                   #  this is expected
#[1] 3                                  
ny <- 1 + 2 * floor(d/rs[2])          # number of rows is 1
ny                                    # this is unexpected
#[1] 1
1 + 2 * floor(d/rs[2])
#[1] 1
2 * floor(d/rs[2])
#[1] 0
floor(d/rs[2])                         # the floor of 1 is 0
#[1] 0
d/rs[2]
#[1] 1
floor(1)                            # but the floor of 1 should be 1
#[1] 1

res(r) == 1                        # the resolution appears to be 1, 1
# [1] 1 1
res(r) == 1                        # but it isn't really
# [1]  TRUE FALSE
```

`?floor` says that unexpected results like this have been seen before.  It says, "It is normally necessary to use a tolerance."

How do I use a tolerance?
How can I fix the `focalWeight` function?

Comment: I used `r <- raster(ncol=2, nrow=1)` then `res(r)<-c(1,1)` to set the same one row, two column matrix with 1,1 in it and then ran your code and got 3 for both nx & ny....not sure why it fails for you. It could be that you have a library loaded which is blocking floor, or has reassigned it with a different calculation.

Comment: I'm calling this function on 9800 images.  It works for all but a few dozen of the images.  Therefore the problem must lie with the images themselves.  The resolution isn't exactly 1 and 1 for these images that cause it to fail.  I think I'd have to send you the image to have you actually reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By using `round`, I can solve the problem.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal) told me how to work with unexpected results of `floor`

```
> floor(d/rs[2])
[1] 0
> floor(d/round(rs[2]))
[1] 1
```

This works in my case where the resolution is 1 1.  I'm not sure about other cases.

Comment: Did the equation actually fail you prior to using round? I tested it and it worked fine....

Comment: the function worked, but it produced a 1x3 matrix instead of a 3x3 matrix.  This caused the focal function, which I called next, to throw an error.

Comment: I just had to create simulated data, so there is a very good chance that it is something hidden in a file and likely not the function, but a format that needs adjusting in some way before passing the image in